# Is there any chance to hide the chrome browser in Selenium using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm using Selenium Framework to automate the browser operations. Currently what I try to do is to hide the browser. Is there any possible chances to hide the Browser and execute the operation silently?

Comment: Not sure about Chrome but you can try http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do that via Selenium.

But, there is an workaround if your code is compiled to an .exe (Console based application) through the Windows Task Scheduler.

If you schedule the .exe file in the Windows Task Scheduler, you will get an option named - Run whether user is logged in or not in General tab of the scheduled task property. Please refer the screen here - [TaskSchedulerProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O5T2.png)

Once you check it and save, the system will prompt for the user name and password for the account through which the task will be executed. Provide correct username and password and save it.

From the next execution all execution for that .exe file will be running in the background.

Hope this helps. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: I find a solution is by using PhantomJS instead of CHrome Driver